# Picking element in iframe using Selenium Java / not able to accept GDPR consent window via automation

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, iframe, automation

I am trying to accept the GDPR Consent window via Selenium (Java), which is placed in an iframe. I understood from the lecture and forums that I have to first switch to that frame (which I did) and then click on the button. However, nothing happens.
Can anyone please help?Thanks

```
import java.time.Duration;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class GDPRiframe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/DDD/WebDrivers/chromedriver");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        
        driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/test/");

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
        
        WebElement frameelement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='gdpr-consent-notice']"));

        driver.switchTo().frame(frameelement);
            
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='save']")).click();   
        
        

    }

}
```

- Verified the css of the object via console, if there is no issue with that - appears to be ok. Also, I tried to click on a link within the frame, also not working. Seems as if I was not switched to the frame.

Thanks

Comment: If I search the xpath `//iframe[@id='gdpr-consent-notice']` I do not find anything in that page. Is your xpath correct? Are you sure url is correct? Because I do not see any popup. What is the error you are getting in your console?

Comment: No such element with id - 'gdpr-consent-notice', is the URL correct?

Comment: hello, thanks for helping out. I just tried again, the owner of the page must have done some changes. I did not change anything in my code and now it started working. The same code that I was trying to debug for days before I asked it here. I do see a popup - when running the automation it's there all the time, I have also now seen that after I deleted cookies, one tab did not show the popup, so I opened a new tab - and that one did. I don't understand this...